# Why textbox is still disabled after removing value from other text box in angular

Tags: angular

I have a angular page with two textboxes. Once user enter value in any of the text box then other text box should get disabled. Below is my code:

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="firstName" [disabled]="lastName"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="lastName" [disabled]="firstName"/>
    </div>
```

This works fine but if I remove value from textbox then other textbox is not getting enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngModel` directive appears to alter the behavior of the `disabled` property binding. The input element is disabled when `ngModel` is applied and `disabled` is bound to an empty string:

```
<input type="text" [disabled]="''" />                 // Enabled
<input type="text" ngModel [disabled]="''" />         // Disabled <== unexpected!!!
<input type="text" ngModel [disabled]="" />           // Enabled
<input type="text" ngModel [disabled]="undefined" />  // Enabled
<input type="text" ngModel disabled />                // Disabled
```

Therefore, if `emptyString` is an empty string, the following control will be disabled:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" [disabled]="emptyString" />    // Disabled
```

You can get the expected behavior by converting the string to a boolean with `!!`:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" [disabled]="!!emptyString" />  // Enabled
```

These behaviors can be observed in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjjtmt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html):